# How to add Facebook login to a Unity game without Gameroom?

Tags: unity, facebook

I'm trying to implement Facebook login with the Facebook SDK for Unity.  The documentation makes it sound pretty straightforward: call [FB.Init](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Init) and then call [FB.LogInWithReadPermissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.LogInWithReadPermissions) and use a callback to handle the response.  At no point does it mention any additional requirements, such as specific gaming clients.

Everything works inside the editor, but when I try to run a build, the Init call fails with the error message "Pipe name not passed to application on start.
 Make sure you are running inside the facebook games client."

...yeah.  That's kind of what I'm trying to specifically *not* do here; this is being built to run on Steam, and I have seen other Steam games offer Facebook authentication, so I know it's possible.  I just don't quite know how, and Facebook's documentation is no help because it doesn't even mention Gameroom in conjunction with these APIs at all!

Does anyone know what the proper way is to set this up?  Using Unity 2019.2.2f1 and Facebook SDK 7.17.2.

Comment: use firebase for it

Comment: @virtouso What does a mobile development platform have to do with anything?  This is being built for Steam, which kinda implies PCs, not mobile, as the hardware.

Comment: The Firebase Unity SDK includes desktop workflow support for a subset of products, enabling certain parts of Firebase to be used in the Unity editor and in standalone desktop builds on Windows, OS X, and Linux. Caution: Firebase Unity SDK desktop support is a beta feature.

Comment: i should be able to use it on pc too

Comment: @virtouso Really?  I didn't know that.  I'll have to check that out...

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?